# Accessing static variable from new thread inside static block causing program freeze

Tags: java, multithreading, static-variables, static-block

It seems that "static block + new thread + static variable" would cause program freeze?

```
public class HelloWorld{
    private static String str  = "Hi";
    
    static{
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(HelloWorld.str);
            }
        });
        
        thread.start();
        try{
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Static block end");
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

The code above would cause program freeze.

While changing static variable to final static variable, like this

```
public class HelloWorld{
    private final static String str  = "Hi";
    
    static{
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(HelloWorld.str);
            }
        });
        
        thread.start();
        try{
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Static block end");
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

or call from original thread, like this

```
public class HelloWorld{
    private static String str  = "Hi";
    static{
        System.out.println(HelloWorld.str);
        System.out.println("Static block end");   
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

would both work.

Not really sure why "static block + new thread + static variable" would cause program freeze?

Comment: The output of `jstack` will help your understanding.

Comment: @JeffHolt What's the reason the new thread is in Object.wait() state?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's waiting for something that can only happen after the static block finishes.

Comment: Program runs to completion if I comment out the `join()` call. I can only _guess_ that the new thread is not allowed to access `str` until `str` has been fully initialized, and becaiuse `str` is assignable, and because a `static` block exists, `str` is not considered to be fully initialized until the main thread has completed execution of the `static` block. I don't actually know how those things are _supposed_ to interact though.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. One strange thing is that accessing static variable from main thread inside static block never put main thread in wait state. Seems like two threads have different criteria on what is fully initialized.